# How to force the gmail inbox to reload/refresh?

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, gmail, page-refresh, google-apps-script-addon

I have built an application that uses the import endpoint in the Gmail API `Gmail.Users.Messages.import()` to clone an email message but allow for subject changing.

It then deletes the original/old message using the remove endpoint `Gmail.Users.Messages.remove()`

I would like a way to refresh the Gmail inbox UI or even to just reload the web page from Google Apps Script - however, I'm not aware of how to do this - and a look around the internet hasn't proven especially helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's not possible to control the user's Gmail interface via an API (or add-on). The best your application could do is instruct the user to do it themselves.